# Heatmap table (ggfluctuation function)

Tags: r

When I run this programming code, I will get this error "ggfluctuation is deprecated. (Defunct; last used in version 0.9.1)". 
1-How can i fix this issue? 
2-In my original data set, I have two string variables with too many levels (first variable with 65 levels and second variable with 8 levels),can I have Heatmap table for these two variables although they have different number of levels? 
3-What is the best way (plot) to show the relationship between these two categorical variables in my data set?

```
library(Hmisc)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
data(HairEyeColor)
P=t(HairEyeColor[,,2])
Pm=melt(P)
ggfluctuation(Pm,type="heatmap")+geom_text(aes(label=Pm$value),colour="white")+ opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(size = 15),axis.text.y=theme_text(size = 15))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to plot a heatmap just use `geom_tile`. Also, `opts` and `theme_text` are deprecated instead and have been replaced by `theme` and `element_text` respectively.

So, you could use this:

```
ggplot(Pm, aes(Eye, Hair, fill=value)) + geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label=Pm$value),colour="white")+ 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size = 15),axis.text.y=element_text(size = 15))
```

Which outputs:

[image]

Also, just to answer all the questions yes, ggplot can handle two categorical columns with a different number of levels and also a heatmap is a nice way to show the relationship between two categorical variables such as the ones you have.

Comment: Great, Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Hi Again, just a question, when i run this code in my data set, i will get this error: Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:melt_table1$value . One of the variables has 13 and the other one has 8 levels. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hi. This is a data related issue, so it would be better to post a new question with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that we can replicate your error and try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The GGally package has a ggfluctuation2 function that replaces the deprecated ggfluctuation. But it's still pretty rough (you can't even specify axis labels) and I prefer the original ggplot function. You can also try ggally_ratio.